Enabling Size Markers/Guides in Adobe Captivate 2023
I am using Adobe Captivate version 2023. While adding elements to a slide, are the size markers (dots on the corners of the selected area to adjust size) around any element not available as such in the software, or is there a mistake I made?
I tried looking for any option that was connected to enabling size markers everywhere - in 'Preferences', TOC, pretty much every option possible.
